# Complex Polynomial and Root of Unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

The polynomial $z^n-1$ can be factorized as $z^n-1=(z-a_1)...(z-a_n)$, where $a_i \in \mathbb{C}$.

I have to show that if $\omega\in\mathbb{C}$ is an $n$th unit root, then $\omega=a_i$ for some $i\in\mathbb{N*}$

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $\omega$ is an $n$th root of unity then $\omega^n-1=0$, and $z^n-1 = (z-a_1)\cdots(z-a_n)$.

Comment: I'm at this point, but missing the idea how to use this. So if there is a $\omega$ such that $(z^n-1)=(z-a_1)...(z-\omega)...(z-a_n)$ what does this tell me?

Comment: @JDizzle $\omega^n-1 = (\omega-a_1)\cdots(\omega-a_n) =0 \implies \omega=? $

Comment: Then there is a  $(\omega -a_k)=0$ so then $\omega^k=0$?

Comment: @JDizzle $\omega -a_k = 0 \implies \omega = a_k$. That's what you wanted to prove. $\omega -a_k = 0$ does not imply that $\omega^k = 0$.